# Firebase: Set text on textview after processing other activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey friends I am using FCM for push notifications, I want to show notification body on an activity. But for this I want that when I click on notification,
1)first it will take me to the activity containing a button "show message" and then 
2) by clicking that button I will be redirected to the activity where notification body message will be shown

What is the way to do this, please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Following in your Notification

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AcitivityWhereyouWantToGo.class);
intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
//System.currentTimeMillis() is used for unique Id
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,0);
```

Now get the value of the boday as

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```

Set this string to your textView where you want to show